# Getting the year from a date property in a query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I know I can get a year from a data using carbon like so.

This gets the current year.

```
$current = Carbon::now();
$year = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current)->year;
```

I have a query which gets all the appointments a user has had. I need to get all appointments had in the current calendar year.

I have the following query

```
$appointments = Appointments::where('id', $id)
                            ->where('event_end_time', '<', $current)
                            ->count();
```

How can i check get the event end times (which is a date) year. For example If the date is 11-05-2018 and can I just get the year (2018) and check if a appointment happened in 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's query builder includes a method for this:

```
whereYear('event_end_time', $year)
```

In raw SQL this is `where year(event_end_time) = ?`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SQL **DATE_FORMAT** function.

```
$appointments = Appointments::where('id', $id)
                        ->where(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(event_end_time, "%Y-%m-%d")), '<', $current)
                        ->count();
```

I think this is better than calculating date by php, as it is done by Database.

[DATE_FORMAT docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)